# Exclude image paths from Search result

Tags: wordpress, search

I have created a wordpress website. It has standard search features comes inbuilt with Wordpress. There is one little(but major) issue with the search facility. It looks for the keyword inside the page content.

e.g. website url is : www.mywebsite.com

And there is an image added inside content with some paragraphs, the html code of it will be like this:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum facere porro aut suscipit nostrum nisi, illo excepturi possimus quibusdam obcaecati blanditiis ex, quos necessitatibus officia recusandae totam aliquid quia. Quasi.</p>

<img src="http://www.mywebsite.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/img/photo.jpg" alt="">

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos consectetur pariatur amet tempore at suscipit, tenetur modi fugiat perspiciatis quaerat distinctio dolor recusandae aliquam consequatur ullam doloremque voluptas quos eaque.</p>
```

So if I search for keyword as **mywebsite**, it returns this page in the search result as it find the keyword **mywebsite** inside the image path below:

www.**mywebsite**.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/img/photo.jpg

And actually this is wrong as the actually page content text doesn't have the keyword **mywebsite** in it.

How do I fix it. There are 2 options here:

1. Find a way to exclude image paths in search result
2. Exclude page_content to be used for search lookup. So it will lookup into post title and other fields but not in the content.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

This should be relatively simple, give this a shot:

```
// Exclude images from search results - WordPress
add_action( 'init', 'exclude_images_from_search_results' );
function exclude_images_from_search_results() {
    global $wp_post_types;

    $wp_post_types['attachment']->exclude_from_search = true;
}
```

Add the following snippet inside your functions.php file. Assuming the images are part of the said posts, this should exclude them. Hope this helps!

**EDIT:**

What I would do then in your place is modify the search results template, or create your own. You can modify the content as you previously mentioned inside the search results template. I've created an example and with this it will extract all image tags within your content, and output your title with the sanitized content (in this case, no images).

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<section id="primary" class="content-area">
    <main id="main" class="site-main">

    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

        <header class="page-header">
            <h1 class="page-title">
                <?php
                /* translators: %s: search query. */
                printf( esc_html__( 'Search Results for: %s'), '<span>' . get_search_query() . '</span>' );
                ?>
            </h1>
        </header><!-- .page-header -->

        <?php
        /* Start the Loop */
        while ( have_posts() ) :

            the_post();

            $post_title = $post->post_title;
            $post_content = $post->post_content;
            $post_content = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", " ", $post_content);          
            $post_content = apply_filters('the_content', $post_content);
            $post_content = str_replace(']]>', ']]>', $post_content);


            echo "<article>";
                echo "<h1>" . $post_title . "</h1>";
                echo "<p>" . $post_content . "</p>";
            echo "</article>";

        endwhile;

        the_posts_navigation();

    else :

        // This is where your no search results output block would be
        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );

    endif;
    ?>

    </main><!-- #main -->
</section><!-- #primary -->
<?php
get_sidebar();
get_footer();
```

Comment: Nope it doesn't work. What your code does is, it excludes the posts that has post type "attachment". It doesn't look into post content, but it looks for the post's type itself.

Comment: Have you tried editing or creating your own search result template? I've updated the solution with an example that removes all image tags by sanitizing the post content. See above.

Comment: My question is about not showing search results that are appearing because of image paths.